# Error when I refresh my index.html page in the browser : Your file was not foundIt may have been moved or deleted. ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND?

Tags: html, css

Basically when i copy the full path of the website into the browser it shows me the contents just fine. However when I refresh the browser whilst editing the code to see how it looks I get the following error message and have to copy the full path again to see the results.

```
Your file was not foundIt may have been moved or deleted. ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND?
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the error is ? Like copying the error message, as it stands, it's really hard to understand the problem you encounter.

Comment: I did copy the error it's in the question at the top

Comment: I put it in the error in the main chat sorry for the confusion

Comment: What does your URL look like? Paste a sample url what you are copy pasting and what it becomes after refreshing browser window.

Comment: C:\Users\moh20\Desktop\Personal Portfolio\index.html       <-- this is the sample url  of the original code then when i refresh i get this url file:///C:/Users/moh20/Desktop/Personal%2520Portfolio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A bit of explaining as to why you are getting %2520 is :

The common space character is encoded as %20. The % character is encoded as %25.

The way you get %2520 is when your url already has a %20 in it, and gets url-encoded again, which transforms the %20 to %2520

`C:\Users\moh20\Desktop\Personal Portfolio\index.html` <-- There is space between personal and portfolio.
If you provide a local file path only, the browser is expected to encode and protect all characters.

So that space which is treated as `%20` is again encoded (only `%` sign needs encoding here) to `%2520`.
**Solution :**
Pass the url along with proper protocol like `file://`

You can do that in two ways :
1. Right-click on your HTML file and select to open it in a browser to view it.
2. Manually type the protocol along with full file path.(or you can just replace `%2520` to `%20` in the second url after refreshing).